# Elasticsearch 6.3: why DateHistogramAggregationBuilder doesn't support JSR-310?

Tags: elasticsearch, timezone, jodatime, jsr310

In ES 6.3 `DateHistogramAggregationBuilder` seems to only support joda `DateTimeZone` and not JSR-310 `ZoneId`. Am I missing something ? (I used to use `DateHistogramBuilder` which support java `ZoneId` but that class is no longer available)